# Jmeter - Set status after few request have been sent

Tags: jmeter

Can I resolve the following scenario by JMeter?:

> 1. Send request1
> 2. Insert response of request1 to request2
> 3. Send request2
> 4. Send request3
> 5. Compare response3 with responce1
> 6. If response3 = responce1 -> setResponseOK() for request2 ELSE Failed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to Resolve this situatuion

> 1. Send request 1
> 2. Capture the response of request 1 in var1(Using correlation-->depending up on your requirement)
> 3. Send request 3 first (as you don't need response of request 2 for input of req 3)
> 4. Capture response of request 3 in var2
> 5. Now hit Request 2 by passing the response of request 1 as an input which is store in var1
> 6. Apply beanshell post processor as a child of request 2
> 7. Now compare Respose of request 1 and 3 inside if condition:
>      if matches make the previous request (i.e. Request 2) pass, else fail

```
  if(vars.get("var1").equals(vars.get("var2")))
 {
 prev.setSuccessful(true);
 }
 else
 {
 prev.setSuccessful(false); 
 }
```

Comment: @KaushlendraJha, thanks for the answer. According to your solution, a "View Results Tree" will contain statuses of 3 requests or am I wrong?

Comment: yea  result tree will contain status for all the three requests but it's up to you whether you want to make 2nd request pass or fail

Answer (score 0):

Design your test as follows:

1. Request 1

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to extract the whole response into a JMeter Variable configured as:

     - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `response1`
     - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
     - Template: `$1$`
2. Request 2: use `${response1}` where required
3. Request 3

   - [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

     - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
     - Patterns to Test -> `${response1}`

Reference material:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your answer, according to your solution I will see all 3 requests in View Results Tree, but my purpose to "see" a status of request2 ONLY and not all 3 requests.